# Min() Subquery in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've been tasked to display the MGR and salary of the lowest paid employee for that manager.

I need to exclude anyone where the MGR is unknown and to also exclude any groups where the minimum salary is less than $1000. The results should be sorted in descending order by salary.

Here is the table:

```
    +-------+--------+-----------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+------+
    | Empno | Ename  |    Job    | Mgr  |  Hiredate  |    Sal    |   Comm    | Dept |
    +-------+--------+-----------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+------+
    |  7839 | KING   | PRESIDENT |      | 11/17/1981 | $5,000.00 | $0.00     |   10 |
    |  7782 | CLARK  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 6/9/1981   | $2,450.00 | $0.00     |   10 |
    |  7934 | MILLER | CLERK     | 7782 | 1/23/1982  | $1,300.00 | $0.00     |   10 |
    |  7902 | FORD   | ANALYST   | 7566 | 12/3/1981  | $3,000.00 | $0.00     |   20 |
    |  7788 | SCOTT  | ANALYST   | 7566 | 12/9/1982  | $3,000.00 | $0.00     |   20 |
    |  7876 | ADAMS  | CLERK     | 7788 | 1/12/1983  | $1,100.00 | $0.00     |   20 |
    |  7369 | SMITH  | CLERK     | 7902 | 12/17/1980 | $800.00   | $0.00     |   20 |
    |  7566 | JONES  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 4/2/1981   | $0.00     | $0.00     |   20 |
    |  7698 | BLAKE  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 5/1/1981   | $2,850.00 | $0.00     |   30 |
    |  7499 | ALLEN  | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 2/20/1981  | $1,600.00 | $300.00   |   30 |
    |  7844 | TURNER | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 9/8/1981   | $1,500.00 | $0.00     |   30 |
    |  7521 | WARD   | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 2/22/1981  | $1,250.00 | $500.00   |   30 |
    |  7654 | MARTIN | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 9/28/1981  | $1,250.00 | $1,400.00 |   30 |
    |  7900 | JAMES  | CLERK     | 7698 | 12/3/1981  | $950.00   | $0.00     |   30 |
    +-------+--------+-----------+------+------------+-----------+-----------+------+
```

Here is my code so far:

```
SELECT EMp.Mgr, EMp.Ename, EMp.Sal AS Sal
FROM EMp
GROUP BY EMp.Mgr, EMp.Ename, EMp.Sal
HAVING (((EMp.Mgr) Is Not Null) AND ((EMp.Sal)>1000))
ORDER BY EMp.Sal DESC;
```

The problem with my current code is that it is not taking into consideration the minimum salary parameter. I believe this needs to be done by using a subquery, though I'm entirely sure how to proceed with that...

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: what is data type of sal column ?

Comment: It is a Currency data type

Comment: could you please try emp.sal > CCur(1000) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT EMp.Mgr, EMp.Ename, EMp.Sal AS Sal
FROM EMp
WHERE emp.Sal = (select MIN(sal) from emp as emp2 where emp2.MGr = emp.Mgr and emp2.sal > 1000)
GROUP BY EMp.Mgr, EMp.Ename, EMp.Sal
HAVING EMp.Mgr Is Not Null
ORDER BY EMp.Sal DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks Jerrad! I believe this did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced by this answer in relation to the $1000 part. Don't you want simply not to list any manager whose lowest paid employee is paid less than that? This code will show all managers who have any employee paid more than $1000.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
with one as 
(
SELECT EMp.Mgr,min(EMp.Sal) MinSlary
FROM EMp
GROUP BY EMp.Mgr
)
select a.Mgr,b.EName,b.Sal from one a
inner join Emp b on a.Mgr=b.Mgr and a.MinSlary=b.Sal
where a.Mgr is not null and a.MinSlary>1000
```

Comment: Hmm I copy/pasted you code exactly and was give the error: "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Comment: Access doesn't support `with` statements.

Comment: Thanks Jerrad, for the Info, i was not aware of it

Answer (score 0):

The following is closely based on Jerrad's answer, but addresses the concern about that which I raised in a comment there:

```
SELECT Emp.Mgr, Emp.Ename, Emp.Sal AS Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE Emp.Sal=(SELECT MIN(sal)
               FROM Emp as Emp2
               WHERE Emp2.MGr = Emp.Mgr
               HAVING min(Emp2.sal) >= 1000)
GROUP BY Emp.Mgr, Emp.Ename, Emp.Sal
HAVING Emp.Mgr Is Not Null
ORDER BY Emp.Sal DESC;
```

Using your sample data, returns the same rows as Jerrad's except for omitting those with manager 7839 or 7698. Amongst others, these two manage staff with salaries of $0 and $950. The way I was interpreting the original question ("exclude any groups where the minimum salary is less than $1000"), these managers *should* be excluded from the results.